# R: emtrends pairwise contrast results change when testing slopes against 0 or 1

Tags: lme4-nlme, post-hoc, trend, contrasts, lsmeans

When performing post-hoc simple slope analysis on my linear mixed effect model in R using emtrends(), I noticed that pairwise slope comparisons showed differences in the significance when I tested all slopes against 0 compared to when testing against 1 in the same function.

**Details:**
I have a mixed effect model with a significant interaction baseline * condition. Outcome and baseline are continuous, condition is a factor with 3 levels: 0, 1, 2.

```
mod<-lmer(outcome~condition*baseline+(1|subject))
```

When investigating the slopes with emtrends() more closely I find that all trends/conditions are significantly different from 0 - the default null (trds$emtrends).

```
trds0<-emtrends(mod, pairwise ~ condition, var = "baseline", infer=TRUE) # or
trds0<-emtrends(mod, pairwise ~ condition, var = "baseline") |> test(null=0)
```

[image: output trds0]

> Cond=condition, CovBLCen =baseline

In trds0$contrasts, pairwise comparison of the conditions show that 0-1 and 0-2 differ significantly but 1-2 is not significant.

Then, I tested the trends against 1 because it is a better reference for my model, results are as expected, conditions 1 and 2 differ from 0 whereas condition 0 is not significant.

```
trds1<-emtrends(mod, pairwise ~ condition, var = "baseline") |> test(null=1)
```

[image: output trds1]

> Cond=condition, CovBLCen =baseline

**Unexpectedly, I found that the pairwise comparisons (trds1$contrasts) are now all significant with different p-values.**

In my understanding, the function estimates slopes for each condition and compares against the null if specified in the first part of the output. In an additional step, since I added pairwise comparisons, pairs of slopes in relation to one another are tested for their significance, which should not be affected by the overall t-test performed on all slopes in the first step.

> I would be very grateful to hear about any possible reasons why this
> is statistically sound, or more insights into the function itself. I
> found only limited material on the functioning of pairwise within
> emtrends/emmeans. I have not provided data or full code since my code
> is running without issue, I'm merely struggling to interpret the
> output. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know how emmeans works in this case but could it be that with your trds1 code the contrast part is now actually testing whether the *difference* between slopes differs from 1?

Comment: You are testing different null hypotheses (H_0: slope1-slope2 = 0, then later H_0: slope1-slope2 = 1), so of course the results are different.  In this example you can actually compute these tests manually, i.e. in the 2nd case, t = (0.452 - 1)/0.112 = -4.9, as shown.